# How can I read a variable line by line?

Tags: linux, sh

I have a variable that when echoed looks like the following:

```
var1
var one
var_one
var_one (1)
```

And I'd like to read it line-by-line into an array but when I do I get this error:

```
-sh: cannot open var1
var one
var_one
var_one (1): File name too long
```

And I'm using this command:

`read -a names < $myVar`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash using \n as delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a herestring:

```
read -a names <<< $myVar
```

`< $myVar` is telling the shell to read from a file named by the contents of `$myvar`, that is, a file named `var1\nvar one\nvar_one\nvar_one (1)` (with literal newlines). Obviously that file doesn't exist, so you're getting the error.  `<<< $myVar` tells the shell to read the contents of the variable itself as the input, not a file named by it.

If a shell doesn't have the herestring, you'll have to `echo` it:

```
echo "$myVar" | read -a names
```

Comment: This works under a normal bourne shell but not in my esxi bourne shell.  Are there other techniques to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with esxi, but it should at least work with `echo`, I've added that.